# How to replace a recursive function call with a stack data structure?

Tags: c++

I have a recursively called function:

```
void func(int a, bool arr[]) {
    ...
    if ( ... ) {
        func(a, arr);
    }
}
```

And call it from my main code like

```
int int_var = 0;
bool bool_array[10];
func(int_var, bool_array);
```

Now I want to use a stack data structure to replace the recursive call of that function.

How can I do this e.g. using `std::stack`?

Comment: I don't understand your question either. Do you perhaps mean how to convert a recursive function to an iterative function? With those search words, you should be able to locate answers online, too.

Comment: What you've shown does not even look like it necessarily should have been recursive to begin with. `while (!done) manipulate_array();`

Comment: _Stack_ is a data structure, _function_ is callable entity of code. Maybe you want to know how call will _use_ stack? (in this case it depends on compiler's ABI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple to replace recursive calls with a loop and using a [`std::stack<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

A function call uses the programs/threads intrinsic function call stack, thus a recursive call of that function just means to push the actual parameter values on the stack.
As soon the function returns, the result is determined, and popped from the stack.

To give a better suited example, I have replaced your `bool[]` array, with a `std::vector<bool>`:

```
 struct params {
     int a;
     std::vector<bool> arr;
 };

 std::stack<params> myStack;

 int int_var = 0;
 std::vector<bool> bool_array;
 // put an initial value onto the stack
 myStack.push(params{int_var,bool_array});
 while(!myStack.empty()) {
     // compute int_var and the bool_array
     if(/* ... */) {
         myStack.push(params{int_var,bool_array});
     }
     else {
         params p = myStack.top();
         myStack.pop();
         // handle results of the previous computation
     }
 }
```